# In flexbox why my buttons seemed compressed?

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, stylesheet

Why the buttons I created seemed compressed when I used flexbox?

Is there a way to make it medium size?

```
render () {
  const listItems = this.state.content.map((data) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Card>
          <Text h5>{data.TITLE}</Text> 
          <Text h5>{data.CONTENT}</Text>

          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="Edit" onPress={this.editAnnouncement} containerStyle={{marginLeft: 10, width: 120}} />
            <Button title="Delete" onPress={this.editAnnouncement} containerStyle={{marginRight: 10, width: 120}} />
          </View>
        </Card>
      </View>
    )
})

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: 15,
  },
});
```

[image: eemed]

Comment: Consider setting `flex-shrink` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I used flexBasis and set it to 40

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    flexBasis: 40,
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
  },
});
```